# ASP.NET Session Load Performance

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, session

I need to calculate some performance numbers for a few custom session storage providers. I need to know how long it takes to rehydrate session and how long it takes to persist it back to the store. None of the providers provide this level of detail in the debug information.

Is there a generic way of tracking session load and store times? I don't think its available in the regular trace.

I've kind of come up with some hacky ways of tracking through another http module, but they seem inaccurate and so would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Would performance counters and timers help? I don't know anything about your implementation, but I think they can give you what you're looking for.